# parseFloat does not work

Tags: jquery, parsefloat

Hello I am using the following code and want to have the result in x_Total with max. 2 digits. 
But am getting the following: 186.26399999999998 for 1.17 * 15920.00 
Where am I mistaken? 
Thanks for your support

```
$("#x_Proza").change(function() { 
var Prozent = parseFloat($("#x_Proza").val()/100);                       
var FreiBetrag = parseFloat($("#x_FBetrag").val());
var Basis = parseFloat($("#x_Basis").val());                       
$("#x_Total").val(parseFloat((Basis- FreiBetrag)*Prozent)).toFixed(2); 
});
```

Comment: You're trying to set `toFixed` after set the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All is fine in your code except this line

```
$("#x_Total").val(parseFloat((Basis- FreiBetrag)*Prozent)).toFixed(2);
// Move the end of val() ( val(...).toFixed(2) )         ^
```

change this to

```
$("#x_Total").val(parseFloat((Basis- FreiBetrag)*Prozent).toFixed(2));
// To the end (so it'd be .val( (...).toFixed(2)) )                 ^
```

toFixed() function was not passed

---

It'd be a lot clearer with different indentation:

Previous:

```
$("#x_Total").val(
    parseFloat(
        (Basis- FreiBetrag)*Prozent
    )
).toFixed(2);
```

New:

```
$("#x_Total").val(
    parseFloat(
        (Basis- FreiBetrag)*Prozent
    ).toFixed(2);
)
```

Comment: Hello Finciuc Sergiu, thanks a lot. It works for me now. mpol_ch

Comment: Hello I am trying to round up the result to the 5 cents with the following code

Comment: Hello I am tying to round up the results to 5 cents with code Math.round(origVal*20)/20; 
Where should I insert? Is that possible to round up this result?

Comment: I am trying to round up the result to the 5 cents with folloing code
Math.round(origVal*20)/20;
Where should I intsert this code in my example? Thanks

Comment: $("#x_Total").val(parseFloat(
Math.round(
((Basis- FreiBetrag)*Prozent)*20)/20).toFixed(2));
});

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue with the following code which round up the results to 5 ode 0 cents

```
$("#x_Total").val(parseFloat(
Math.round(
((Basis- FreiBetrag)*Prozent)*20)/20).toFixed(2));
});
```

Thanks.